# The globalization/society

Tags: definite-article

Should the definite article be used before both "globalization" and "the consumer society"?

"Globalization created the consumer society."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

The word "globalization"  does not normally take any article, definite or indefinite. Indeed, I cannot think of a usage where it would take an article. On the other hand, the phrase "the consumer society" is very commonly used with an article. It could be used in some contexts without an article, but that is a significantly less common usage. Perhaps:

> Consumer society has developed gretly in the past 30 years.

Even there, a definite article would be likely.

The word "globalization"  here is a noun describing a process or a condition, formed from the verb "globalize". This kind of noun, particularly when ending in "-ization", rarely takes an article. Some examples would be:

> - Synchronization is best achieved by carefully tuning the motor.
> - Thursday is the scheduled date for formalization of the agreement (*this one could take an article.*)
> - Formalization of the agreement requires a physical signature.
> - Standardization of connection sockets on smart phones simplifies shopping for the consumer.
> - Bastardization of foreign words is a common practice.
> - Militarization of the police can lead,to over-escalation.

Comment: This answer applies to abstract nouns  in general. They are usually uncountable: that's why they don't need an indefinite article, and when talking about them in general terms they don't need a definite article either.  Exceptions include expressions like "keeping the peace".

Comment: @JavaLatte Abstract nouns can often take articles, for example""You could have cut the tension with a knife" "I wonder what the whether will be" "I like to watch the seasons turn" "culture is often expressed in the arts". "The play shows a slice of life"

Comment: @David Siegel, I can use either "a consumer society" "the "consumer society" or "consumer society" in my sentence. Right? Or is it used with the definite article or zero article but not the indefinite article?

Comment: @Antonia One may use a definite article, an indefinite article ot no article here, but the definite is mush more common with this phrase, in my experience.

Comment: David Siegel, is it the same with humanity? Can the definite, indefinite or zero article be used before it? "New discoveries are a good step for the humanity/for the humanity."

Comment: As the exception you allow indicates, post-modification can change the game: **The invention of shipping containers in 1956 helped advance *the globalization* of commerce.**